# Removing majority of orderers from OrdererAddresses section in channel in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, raft

Consider the following situation:

1. I am running `fabric-samples/first-network` for the HLF in RAFT mode.
2. I use the CLI container to fetch the latest block for `mychannel` and edit the `OrdererAddresses` section by removing 4 orderers namely, `orderer2.example.com`, `orderer3.example.com`, `orderer4.example.com`, `orderer5.example.com` from it.

I am assuming this should disturb RAFT protocol because orderers are meant to communicate with one another by looking at the endpoints in `OrdererAddresses` section.

Now, the issue is that, despite the above fact, the RAFT keeps working fine. I wait for `10 minutes`, assuming RAFT would break after `EvictionSuspicion` timeout as no longer leader can comunicate to other orderers. But this does not happen. I am still able to read blocks from the `mychannel` as well as I am able to submit new transactions (`invoke` operations) on the chaincode on that channel.

This means that `OrdererAddresses` are not looked into while communicating. Please correct me if I am wrong. By this, I need to know:

**What is the exact functionality of OrdererAddresses section in the RAFT channels?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I learnt that RAFT orderers communicate to one another using the
>   `host` and `port` properties of the `Consenters` section for the
>   purpose of consensus messages. The endpoints present in the
>   `OrdererAddresses` section are used for replication of blocks.

The learning could be verified from [here](https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/message/8290) as answered by Yacov M.